# How to remove a prepros project from outside the app

Tags: prepros

I have unintentionally made my desktop a prepros project and prepors can't process all of the files so when I go to open prepros it crashes making it virtually useless. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app but Desktop is still a project. I have also removed the prepros config file from my desktop. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config containing the project folders is here:

```
C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Roaming\io.prepros.6\config.json
```

There's a object called *projectPaths* with a list of projects you've added. I believe each project stores settings in a local .json file as well.

I had the same 'crash on boot' issue and found that the config files aren't removed when you reinstall Prepros, so the only option is to delete them or modify them yourself.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I accidentally dragged my Sites folder in to the app and Prepros basically crashed on startup until I found that json file.